# Use a variable to reference a web server control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In C#, I want to assign all 10 Checklistboxes on my page with a value (e.g. 1). What is the syntax so that I can use a variable? I.e. `checklistbox(i).selectedIndex = 1;`

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
  checklistbox1.selectedIndex = 1;
  checklistbox2.selectedIndex = 1;
  checklistbox3.selectedIndex = 1;
  ...
  checklistbox10.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: You should name your controls.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should use "FindControl" method inorder to do that as shown below.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
 {
      (Page.FindControl("checklistbox" + i) as CheckBox).SelectedIndex = 1;
 }
```

"checklistbox" is assumed as "ID" that is prefixed for all the checkboxes.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I tried this, but I unfortunately it doens't recognize the SelecteIndex......'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' could be found

Comment: If you are using a checkbox, you can only set the "Checked" property of it. If you are using a checkboxlist, you can set the "SelectedIndex" but only of the items in the list and not for all of them. Please review your requirement.

Comment: I am using many CheckListBoxes that each have 3 "checks". The user can only select 1 value at a time because I have javascript (mutual exclusion function) running on their browswers. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all the controls on the page and pick out the ones you need as described [in this blog post by Kris Steele](http://www.krissteele.net/blogdetails.aspx?id=104):

```
foreach (Control masterControl in Page.Controls)
{
    if (masterControl is MasterPage)
    {
        foreach (Control formControl in masterControl.Controls)
        {
            if (formControl is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm)
            {
                foreach (Control contentControl in formControl.Controls)
                {
                    if (contentControl is ContentPlaceHolder)
                    {
                        foreach (Control childControl in contentControl.Controls)
                        {
                            if(childControl is CheckBoxList)
                            {
                                ((CheckBoxList)childControl).SelectedIndex = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This may not be a good idea if you have a lot of controls on the page.

Comment: This could get gucky because I do have quite a few controls on my page. The page is essentially a large checklist.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `List<CheckBoxList>`:

```
var cbs = new List<CheckBoxList> { thingy, otherThingy, ... };

foreach (var cb in cbs)
     cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
```